# VSCode Extension Development :: Git.registerCredentialsProvider NOT Registering my provider

Tags: vscode-extensions

We're building an extension for VSCode and we want to access the VSCode's built-in git extension `vscode.git`. So I'm registering a credentials provider in the git api but apparently it's never being called...

Here is my code:

```js
class MyGitCredentialsProvider implements CredentialsProvider {

    getCredentials(host: Uri): Promise<Credentials> {
        console.log(`REQUESTED CREDENTIALS FOR HOST :: ${host}`);
        return {
            username: "USERNAME",
            password: "PASSWORD"
        };
    }

}

const gitExtension = vscode.extensions.getExtension('vscode.git').exports;
const gitApi = gitExtension.getAPI(1);

gitApi.registerCredentialsProvider(new MyGitCredentialsProvider());
```

Any ideas how can I make this work?

Thanks in advance!